# C++ - g++ casting int to double gives negative value

Tags: c++, casting, int, double

Was working on a project with mingw on windows :

```
C:\Users\...>g++ -dumpversion
4.5.0
```

When I compiled the code under g++ v 4.2.4 I was getting a segmentation fault - after couple hours I pinned it down to the line :

```
double decimal = ((double) rand()) / (RAND_MAX + 1);
```

For some reason this was giving negative values (and one thing led to another).
What reason ?

Edit : cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Random.h"
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
double Random::exponential(int T) {
    double decimal = ((double) rand()) / (RAND_MAX + 1);
    //  std::cout << "decimal : " << decimal << std::endl;
    return log(1 - decimal)*(-T);
}
//etc
```

h:

```
#ifndef RANDOM_H
#define RANDOM_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
class Random {
public:
    static double exponential(int T);
    static int random_int(int min, int max);
    static bool coin(); //50% true 50% false
};

#endif  /* RANDOM_H */
```

just noticed the double include (of math.h) but this shouldn't be an issue

Comment: That shouldn't happen normally.  There may be some problem with how rand() is declared.

Comment: Don't use unsafe C-style casts in C++ (ever).  Try using static_cast or something else and see how it goes.

Comment: @John - could you elaborate ?

Comment: Do not do this in C++: `(double) rand()`.  Instead do something like `static_cast<double>(rand())`.  The reason is that the C-style cast is unsafe and says to the compiler "I don't care how silly this expression looks, just mash the bits together how I say."  The C++ style casts do something more specific and will give an error if the expression does not make sense (such as static_casting a pointer into a double or something).

Comment: @JohnZwinck C-style casts are perfectly safe when casting numeric types, because they become `static_cast`s anyway

Comment: @SethCarnegie: The whole point is to prevent a *mistake*. But **obviously**, it works fine if used correctly... (though personally I'd rather just assign implicitly to a `double` variable first.)

Comment: @Mehrdad I take exception when someone says "never do this" as if they know what's best for someone in every situation.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Sure they're safe if you get them right.  But if you meant to say `(double)*myValue` and you forgot the star, the compiler will happily make your pointer into a double.  That's why it's unsafe, and I will stand by my statement that C-style casts have no place in C++ code.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I do not see **any reason** in *any situation* to say `(double) rand()` in C++ -- so even though John never said "never", I think that would be the appropriate word anyway.

Comment: @Mehrdad he said "Don't use unsafe C-style casts in C++ (ever)", and "don't" + "ever" = "never"

Comment: @SethCarnegie: My bad, I missed that comment. I guess "never" might be too broad, yeah.

Comment: Just a breadcrumb for anyone who wants to read more about C++ style casts vs. C ones in C++ code: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/50442/c-style-casts-or-c-style-casts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, `RAND_MAX` is the maximum value for the integer type it is stored in, so `RAND_MAX + 1` gives you the maximum negative value. Technically this is signed integer overflow which is undefined behaviour so anything can happen.

You need to do, as J-16 pointed out,

```
double decimal = (double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1);
```

Comment: or `(double)RAND_MAX + 1`, if you want to have `[0,1)`.

Comment: Well well - just a detail - I am explicitly - using () - casting the rand() part to double. It never faulted once in 4.5.5 in 10^5 runs and it immediately faults in 4.2.4. How come ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D because you are dividing it by a negative value (because `RAND_MAX` is defined as the maximum value that the integer type can hold, which, when you add 1 to it, becomes the maximum negative value) which results in a negative value

Comment: To know for sure why it fails with one compiler and not with another version you may have to inspect the generated code.  Also, make sure you're using the same compiler options on each.

Comment: @JohnZwinck you don't have to go as far as inspecting the generated code, it's a simple case of undefined behaviour which leads to division by a negative number

Comment: Your explanation is right, but your "fixed" expressions make no sense to me.  I think the operator precedence is all wrong.  And subtracting 1 from `rand()` can potentially give you a negative result also.

Comment: Thank you - but why on earth on 4.2.4 ? Seriously I run this thing a zillion times on 4.5.0 without this happening. Moreover `(double)rand() - 1` could give a negative value to begin with (if rand() returns 0.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, I removed the parens mistakenly, fixed before you commented :)

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Sure the behavior may be undefined but if there is a noticeable difference between two compiler versions and one wants to know what the difference really is, looking at the generated code might be interesting.  Obviously the solution is to fix the source code.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D because 4.2.4 defines it differently. It's perfectly legal.

Comment: @JohnZwinck the difference is that 4.2.4 defines `RAND_MAX` differently.

Answer (score 1):

In your environment, `RAND_MAX` is probably set to the highest positive number, such as `0x7fff` (32767). When you add one to that, it actually wraps around to the lowest negative number, such as `0x8000` (-32768). This all assumes two's complement of course and that the number will wrap, neither of which are mandated by the standard).

So, because you're dividing the positive-or-zero value from `rand` by a negative value, you'll end up with a negative number most of the time, and zero occasionally.

You can use `RAND_MAX` in the division instead of `RAND_MAX+1`. This will avoid giving you a negative number but then you'll run into another problem.

Because there's a possibility that `rand` will return `RAND_MAX`, the division may give you a result of 1. When you then try to calculate `log (1 - decimal) * (-T)`, that's taking the logarithm of zero and you'll end up with an error: `log(0)` is not defined in mathematics.

I would suggest simply avoiding that problem by using something like this:

```
double Random::exponential (int T) {
    int randVal = rand();
    while (randVal == RAND_MAX)
        randVal = rand();

    double decimal = (double) randVal / RAND_MAX;
    return log (1 - decimal) * (-T);
}
```

This will avoid the edge cases at the cost of the occasional double call to `rand`.